# Performance issues with ActiveMQ Artemis and Spring JmsTemplate

Tags: spring-boot, jms, spring-jms, activemq-artemis

While doing some load tests with the ActiveMQ Artemis broker and my Spring Boot application I am getting into performance issues.

What I am doing is, sending e.g. 12,000 messages per second to the broker with JMSeter and the application receives them and saves them to a DB. That works fine. But when I extend my application by a filter mechanism, which forwards events after saving to DB, back to the broker using `jmsTemplate.send(destination, messageCreator)` it goes very slow.

I first used ActiveMQ 5.x and there this mechanism works fine. There you could configure the `ActiveMQConnectionFactory` with `setAsyncSend(true)` to tune performance. For the ActiveMQ Artemis `ConnectionFactory` implementation there is no such a possibility. Is there another way to tune performance like in ActiveMQ 5.x?

I am using Apache ActiveMQ Artemis 2.16.0 (but also tried 2.15.0), artemis-jms-client 2.6.4, and Spring Boot 1.5.16.RELEASE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first thing to note is that you need to be very careful when using Spring's JmsTemplate to send messages as it employs a well-known anti-pattern that can really kill performance. It will actually create a new JMS connection, session, and producer for *every* message it sends. I recommend you [use a connection pool like this one](https://github.com/messaginghub/pooled-jms) which is based on the ActiveMQ 5.x connection pool implementation but now supports JMS 2. For additional details about the danger of using JmsTemplate see the [ActiveMQ documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/jmstemplate-gotchas). This is also discussed in [an article from Pivotal](https://community.pivotal.io/s/article/Using-Connection-Pooling-with-JMSTemplate-in-Spring-Framework?language=en_US) (i.e. the "owners" of Spring).

The second point here is that you *can* tune if persistent JMS messages are sent synchronously or not using the `blockOnDurableSend` URL property, e.g.:

```
tcp://localhost:61616?blockOnDurableSend=false
```

This will ensure that persistent JMS messages are sent asynchronously. This is discussed further in the [ActiveMQ Artemis documentation](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/send-guarantees.html#non-transactional-message-sends).

Comment: I also added "<journal-sync-non-transactional>false</journal-sync-non-transactional>", so i combination it works now much better.

Comment: Keep in mind that while relaxing disk synchronization requirements increases performance it increases the possibility that you will lose data in case of a crash.